# How would I print a statement with a number at the end, but set the number from right to left at a certain lenght?

Tags: java, printf

I'm very new to coding, and this I don't know anything beyond simple formatting and Boolean statement. What I'm trying to print is:

```
Gross Pay:     $   0.00
```

My code is:

```
System.out.printf("Gross Pay:     " + "$" + "%.2f\n", grossPay);
```

and the output is

```
Gross Pay:     $0.00
```

I believe I'm suppose to print from right to left with 7 space length. How would I do that?

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't more specific. I wasn't necessary asking for if it's valid or not, but I was asking how to get it to be exactly `Gross Pay:     $   0.00` with the space and all. My actual question is how to get the `$   0.00`, having the space 3 between $ and 0.00 being automatic as oppose to just doing `+ "   " +` .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (Edited):

```
String.format("%7.2f", value)
```

Sample:

```
System.out.println("Gross Pay:     $" + String.format("%7.2f", 10.01));
System.out.println("Gross Pay:     $" + String.format("%7.2f", 100.01));
System.out.println("Gross Pay:     $" + String.format("%7.2f", 1000.01));
System.out.println("Gross Pay:     $" + String.format("%7.2f", 10000.01));
```

Sample Output:

```
Gross Pay:     $  10.01
Gross Pay:     $ 100.01
Gross Pay:     $1000.01
Gross Pay:     $10000.01
```

As an alternative to using spaces, this is a sample with number padding:

```
        DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat();
        currency.setGroupingUsed(false);
        currency.setMinimumIntegerDigits(12);
        currency.setMaximumIntegerDigits(12);
        currency.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        currency.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        currency.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        System.out.println("Gross Pay:     $" + currency.format(939394.02480240));
```

Comment: This is the closest to solution I've gotten, thank you. Is there a way to keep decimal at 2 place whilst reserving 7 space? My number is based on input, so if the input calculates to ```1000.10``` it would output ```1000.1``` currently with a space in front being the place holder space.

Comment: Added an update. As long as the length <= 7 this should work. If it is longer than 7, data will not be trimmed. Depending on the usage, an exception may be thrown or the value may be used as is.

Comment: You are a national hero. bless.

Answer (score 0):

It could be valid if you print it like this: System.out.printf("Gross Pay:     " + "$   " + "%.2f\n", grossPay); ?

Comment: Appreciate the input, but please read my newly added edit.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, hope this could help:`code`double pi = Math.PI;
  System.out.format("Gross Pay:     $"+"%10.2f%n",pi);`code`